# How is it possible to map column names from a Doctrine sql query?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query, doctrine-dbal

I created a query with query builder like this:

```php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(['u.id', 'u.name'])
   ->from(User::class, 'u')
   ->where('u.active = 1')
;
$sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();
```

The result looks like this:

```
SELECT u1_.user_id as s1, u1_.full_name as s2 FROM users u1_ WHERE u1_.is_active = 1
```

I would like to execute it as a native query, but I have to find out, how to map `s1, s2` to `id, name`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `as` inside your select

using your example =>

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(['u.id as s1', 'u.name as s2'])
   ->from(User::class, 'u')
   ->where('u.active = 1');
$sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSql();
```

this maps id to `s1` and name as `s2`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question but if you want to run a native query with, in the result, the columns `id` and `name`, you can replace them in the query, they're aliases so they can be anything you want :

```
SELECT u.user_id as id, u.full_name as name FROM users u WHERE u.is_active = 1
```